# Laravel Scheduler Skipping certain Jobs but Dispatching another on Server but Works perfectly fine on Localhost

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord

I have created 2 jobs, namely "DailySalesSummaryAmazon" and "AmazonAccountHealthSummary". I am trying to dispatch these jobs everyday at 9:30 AM. Somehow, the first job is not getting dispatched but the second one "AmazonAccountHealthSummary" gets dispatched and executed perfectly on server.

On the other hands when I test the same code on my localhost, every job is being dispatched and being processed well. I am unable to fix this issue. I tried restarting the supervisor workers on the server but to no avail.

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Channel;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Jobs\SyncLastDayAmazonOrders;
use App\Jobs\SyncLastDayFlipkartOrders;
use App\Jobs\SyncLastHourFlipkartOrders;
use App\Models\WhatsAppNotificationModel;
use App\Jobs\FetchAmazonAccountPerformance;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use App\Jobs\inventory\CheckAmazonInventoryLevel;
use App\Jobs\WhatsappNotification\DailySalesSummaryAmazon;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use App\Jobs\WhatsappNotification\DailySalesSummaryFlipkart;
use App\Jobs\WhatsappNotification\AmazonAccountHealthSummary;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function(){
            $allChannels=Channel::all();
            foreach( $allChannels as $channel){

                $sub=Subscription::where('user_id','=',$channel->user_id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();

                $subExpiryDate=$sub->expiry_date;
                $validSubscription=($subExpiryDate >= Carbon::now())?1:0;
                Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info("User subscription expiry date for channel ID: $channel->user_id is : $subExpiryDate");
                if($validSubscription){
                    Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info("Subscription is valid for channel ID: $channel->id");
                    $whatsappSubscription=WhatsAppNotificationModel::where('user_id','=',$channel->user_id)->first();
                    if(!is_null($whatsappSubscription))
                    {
                        Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info("Found a whatsapp no. for the channel ID: $channel->id");
                        if($channel->order_sync_status){
                            Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info("Order sync is enabled for the given channel; Trying to dispatch job for whatsapp; ");
                            Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info("Channel details are as given below: Channel ID: $channel->id; $channel->channel_name; Store Name: $channel->store_name");
                            
                            if($channel->channel_name=='amazon')
                                {
                                    Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info('Dispatching Daily Sales Summary Job for : Amazon Channel='.$channel->id);
                                    DailySalesSummaryAmazon::dispatch($channel->id); 
                                    AmazonAccountHealthSummary::dispatch($channel->id);
                                    Log::channel('scheduledjobslog')->info('Dispatching Daily Account Health Summary Job for : Amazon Channel='.$channel->id);
                                    
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })->dailyAt('9:30');
    }

}
```

`

Tried restarting the supervisor workers: sudo supervisorctl restart saral-queue:*
Cleared compiled services and package files using php artisan clear-compiled

Comment: Have you checked on jobs table? if its nothing in there, try check failed_jobs table?

Comment: @AndreHaykal Yes, I checked the jobs as well as failed_jobs table, there is no entry there.

Comment: test it on your server using php artisan schedule:work

Comment: This is already part of a cron job that runs every minute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel scheduling works based on a certain time, like if you will run any task every 2 minutes, then it will run x:02, x:04, x:06 minutes, similarly for every 5 minutes it will run x:05, x:10, x:15.

If you have multiple tasks running inside scheduling and one task is taking time then it will skip jobs whose time is consumed by the previous task.
Like, if you have set up a task to run at 23:05, and before that, there is another task that is taking 4-5 minutes to run and the scheduler starts at 23:04 and 4 minutes are consumed by the first task then your 23:05 task will get skipped.